# Auto alignment in table

Tags: tables

In the following MWE i have been trying some formula in tabular for but unfortunately content is not well arranged. Please solve this problem. I mean is there any way that content of table gets auto alignment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=0.7in, right=0.7in, top=0.7in, bottom=0.7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Type of Data   & Direct Method                                   & Short-cut Method                                  \\ \hline
    Ungrouped Data & $\overline{x}=\dfrac{\Sigma x}{n}$        & $\overline{x}=A+\dfrac{\Sigma d}{n} $        \\ \hline
    Grouped Data   & $\overline{x}=\dfrac{\Sigma fx}{n}$        & $\overline{x}=A+\dfrac{\Sigma fd}{n} $  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.5}` before the `tabular`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would typeset the equation columns as two separate columns, one right justified and the other left justified. This produces:

[image]

I have taken a few liberties here. As explained in the [booktabs manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs), there are good reasons for not putting vertical rules into tables, so I have taken these out (they are easy to put back in if you want them. I have also used `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` from `booktgabs` for the horizontal rules. Finally, in the `tabular` environment specification I have used `@{\ }` to add better spacing around the equals sign and I have manually adjusted the space between rows 2 and 3 using `\\[4mm]` because otherwise the fractions collided.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[left=0.7in, right=0.7in, top=0.7in, bottom=0.7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cr@{\ }lr@{\ }l} \toprule
    Type of Data   & \multicolumn2c{Direct Method}             & \multicolumn2c{Short-cut Method}             \\ \midrule
    Ungrouped Data & $\overline{x}$ & $=\dfrac{\Sigma x}{n}$   & $\overline{x}$ & $=A+\dfrac{\Sigma d}{n} $   \\[4mm]
    Grouped Data   & $\overline{x}$ & $=\dfrac{\Sigma fx}{n}$  & $\overline{x}$ & $=A+\dfrac{\Sigma fd}{n} $  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The equations are not centered in their columns, so this isn't exactly what you asked for.